# SQL, filter pattern with data format on end of field value

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-like

in SQl code how can be filtered out values that match the following pattern:

some characters and after the last underscore ('_') has a date in the format DDMMYYY,

example

```
values
-----
hello01122015
hello_2000
22_text_01022015
hello_again_22012015
```

### result:

```
22_text_01022015
hello_again_22012015
```

Regards

Comment: What RDBMS? If it has regular expressions, use that.

Comment: How this row is in result `hello_2000`

Comment: Is `2000` really in `DDMMYYYY` format?

Comment: sorry forgot to mentioned, It can be postgresql or mysql :)

Comment: "is 2000 really in DDMMYYYY format?"   no, that;s why it will not be filtered out.

Comment: but it is in result can you explain

Comment: Sorry you are right! Fixed the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regular expression `'_[0-9]{8}$'` for this & check that the actual date is valid:

```
-- with PostgreSQL
select *
from   t
where  values ~ '_[0-9]{8}$' and
       to_char(to_date(right(values, 8), 'DDMMYYYY'), 'DDMMYYYY') = right(values, 8);

-- with MySQL
select *
from   t
where  `values` regexp '_[0-9]{8}$' and
       str_to_date(right(`values`, 8), '%d%m%Y') is not null;
```

Or, you can use more robust regular expression, like `'_(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[0-9]{4}$'`, but that won't be bullet-proof (this can accept *some* invalid date).

SQLFiddle: for [PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/90882/14), for [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a3d0/12)

**Note**: `values` is a reserved word in SQL, please avoid as a column name, if you can.